# Why can a python dictionary be modified in the variable of a list comprehension?

Tags: python, obfuscation, language-features

From an amazing (and evil) video about the [Oneliner-izer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsUxuz_Rt8g&t=16m20s), I learned that a Python dictionary can be modified in the variable of a list comprehension. I tried to run the following code:

```py
some_dict = dict()
some_dict['x'] = 1
return_value = [999 for some_dict['x'] in [42]][0]
```

It is clear to me that `return_value` should now be `999`, but why should `some_dict['x']` now be `42`? How is the list comprehension syntax even legal? Let alone modifying `some_dict`?

Comment: Well for example, you could do `[999 for x in some_list]` -  this sets `x` to each value in `some_list`. So, if instead of using `x`, you use a value from a `dict`, it still works exactly the same; it sets `some_dict['x']` to each value in `some_list` (which in this case just has one item, `42`).

Comment: Right.  It's exactly the same as `...for i in [42]`, which sets the variable `i` to 42.  It shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: Thank you both. In hindsight this is obvious. Somehow I thought that the variable in a list comprehension needed to be a "new thing" rather than "extracted" from somewhere else.

Comment: `list` comprehensions have their own scope, however, this is no different than setting it in the body of a function. It works because it's mutating `some_dict`. Iteration over a collection is just an assignment. It doesn't necessarily have to be new.